# What is the red X on my CSS file icon in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana3

I have a CSS file for a Wordpress theme whose icon is overlayed with a red "X". I can't find any errors in the file. The CSS is working properly on the site, and I tried turning off the CSS validator in preferences as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652793/how-can-i-suppress-certain-css-errors-in-aptana-studio-3).

Here is a screenshot of what the red X on the icon looks like:

[image]

Is this some other kind of validation I can turn off or is there something in the CSS I *must* fix to get Aptana to stop whining?

Comment: Do you see a little red X anywhere on the left margin to the left of the line numbers when you open the file?  I think that the file parsing is not perfect in Studio 3 yet.  There are instances in my Rails project where it finds syntax errors where there are none.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this indicates a validation problem with the file. To disable it do the following:

Open your project and navigate to Window -> Preferances -> Aptana Studio -> Validation

Un-Check the grren check under "Build" in the CSS Syntax Validator.

It should prompt you to do a "full rebuild", select "yes", after this you should notice the "red X" disappear.